# Having a 2nd admin page for a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

Right now, I understand by registering a custom post type, a list/edit page for it will appear in the admin menu in wp-admin.

Is it possible to have a second list or edit page for the custom post type? The situation is that I am adding a functionality to WooCommerce's shop_order custom post type. If the user is of a certain role, he is able to view a limited info of the shop_order posts. So I would like to add in another admin page that would display the custom_post_type without messing with WooCommerce's one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is absolutely possible.

Have a look at the [`add_menu_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) function and use it like so:

```
add_menu_page(
    'My 2nd CPT Menu',               // page title
    'My 2nd CPT Menu',               // menu title
    'edit_post'                      // required cap, same as in register_post_type()
    'edit.php?post_type=yourCPT',    // edit.php + query string as slug <-- this is essential
    '',                              // empty callback
    'relpath/to/icon.png',           // optional icon file
    101                              // optional menu position
);
```

Analogously, this can be done in a very similar fashion with [submenu pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page).

Comment: Thank you; however, if I don't specify a callback, does this means it will use back whatever admin settings the custom post type already has? Is there anyway to ovide a custom set of settings (such as what column is displayed and etc.) for the 2nd CPT admin page?